# ActionController::UnknownFormat when using custom actions to change user password in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a custom action for updating my user account information. This [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) has been very helpful, but I get a `ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#account` error when following option 3.

My routes are looking like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
 registrations: 'users/registrations',
 sessions: 'users/sessions',
 passwords: 'users/passwords',
 confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
 unlocks: 'users/unlocks'
}

resource :user, only: [:edit], path: "settings" do
 member do
  get 'account'
  get 'password'
  patch 'update_account'
  patch 'update_password'
 end
end
```

And then the controller they say to set up looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def account
  @user = current_user
 end
end
```

`rake routes` looks like this:

```
account_user GET    /settings/account(.:format)                             users#account
```

And when I go to localhost:3000/settings/account (where I have an **account.html.erb** file), I get this error: `UsersController#account is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not… nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.`

Why?

Comment: Are you sure that template exists as `app/views/users/account.html.erb`?

Comment: oops i had it in `/users/settings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates for `UsersController` must contains in `app/views/users` directory by default.

If you want use custom template directory for controller's action use something like:

```rb
def account
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html { render '/users/settings/account.html.erb' } 
  end
end
```